# Writing a dictionary to replace switch statements in functions

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

I've written a menu in Python 3 that takes user input, however to convert the string properly I've had to manually write out an if statement.

I need to change this all to a dictionary to use across several different functions, storing variables in some and lists in another. So far the if statement looks like this. I've only pasted 'a', but 'b' is similar.

```
while loop == 1:
choice = menu()
if choice == '1':
    a = str(input("Enter a note: "))
    b = str(input("Enter an interval: "))

    if a == "Bs" or a == "C": 
        a = 0
    elif a == "Cs" or a == "Db":
        a = 1
    elif a == "D":
        a = 2
    elif a == "Ds" or a == "Eb":
        a = 3
    elif a == "E":
        a = 4
    elif a == "Es" or a == "F":
        a = 5
    elif a == "Fs" or a == "Gb":
        a = 6
    elif a == "G":
        a = 7
    elif a == "Gs" or a == "Ab":
        a = 8
    elif a == "A":
        a = 9
    elif a == "As" or a == "Bb":
        a = 10
    elif a == "B" or a == "Cb":
        a = 11
```

And here's the add() function I've written.

```
def add(a,b):
print ((a), "+", (b), "=", (a + b) %12)
```

I think I need to store all these variables somewhere in a dictionary, and have the function check against them there rather than in an if statement every time. I've read about dictionaries as switch statements in Python but don't understand.

```
def f(x):
return {
    'C': 0,
    'D': 2,
}[x]
```

What's the difference between this and a normal dictionary?

```
notes = {'C' = '0': 'D' = '2'}
```

Thank you!

Comment: nothing .... it is "a normal dictionary" its just returned by a function

Comment: Yes. You need to do something like that. You might also consider creating a class and having this dict as a *class variable* available to all functions and objects of that class. You could think of this as a "local global" -- it's 'global' in the sense they can all reference it without it being passed explicitly, but it's local in the sense that it doesn't pollute the namespace.

Comment: That might be best, then I can access this switch dictionary across any function and I don't need to repeat it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* a normal dictionary.  The difference is that your "switch" dictionary is an in-line constant with an index.  Let's expand this just a little:

```
def f(x):
    ref_dict = {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
    }

    return_tone = ref_dict[x]
    return return_tone
```

Do you see how this works?  Now, replace **return_tone** in the last line with **ref_dict[x]**, and the replace **ref_dict** with the constant dictionary value.

Comment: Okay I understand that now. What is 'x' standing for in this example? Does this switch dictionary need to come after my user input?

Comment: Yes.  This is a function that takes a note name -- such as "Cs" -- and returns the integer matching the semi-tone in the scale.  For instance, you feed it "Cs" and get back 1.  Of course, you have to fill out the entire dictionary first; the one here handles only A and B (and has the wrong values, at that).

Comment: Great! I've filled out the dictionary and placed it after the a = str(input) but I'm now getting a 'Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly' error. What do I need to convert exactly?

Comment: That depends on what you *have* exactly.  This should be posted as a new question, including the current code (now that it's no longer built from pieces) and the full error message (including stack trace).  If you haven't read the posting guidelines yet, this might be a good time to refer to [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).